# How can we add a button inside an AR portal in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am given a task to **add a button at the end of the portal with either containing *3d model or 360 video***, where entry should be from AR portal, but the user should click the button to redirect to a website to get an exit from the portal and end the game. How can I achieve this task?

Can you share a demonstration video or link to reference docs to learn a bit more about that?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using portal, Unity is creating 3D environment. Here you can provide button or object same as working with 3D. Provide 3d collider to the button and give it special tag. Use Ray cast method ( ScreenPointToRay ) for detecting 3d collider. And play with OnCollisionEnter method for redirect to website.